# date code in php displaying 01/01/1970

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

this portion of code is outputing 01/01/1970. is my code incorrect? i have only posted the relevant part because it is part of a json page. the table field is date format. thanks

```
date('d/m/Y',$row['destroy_date'])
```

Comment: Yes its correct if `row['destroy_date']` equals `1970-01-01`. Is it ?

Comment: @skowron. this is the date in the db: 2028-09-12. thanks

Comment: skowron-line, no, it's correct if `$row['destroy_date']` equals any value from 0 to 82799.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `$row['destroy_date']` is not a UNIX timestamp, parse it with [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) first:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['destroy_date']))
```

Read in the manual for [date](http://php.net/date) and you'll see that the second argument cannot be a date in any format.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion and produces this error: strtotime() [<a href='function.strtotime'>function.strtotime</a>]: Called with empty time parameter. thanks

Comment: bollo, that error suggests that `$row['destroy_date']` is not set while runnign that row. Make sure that the rest of your logic is in fact correct (try to echo the value of `$row['destroy_date']` in the same place is you run the date function right now).

Comment: i have tried to echo the value but keeps erroring with , error expected. this is the portion that displays the date. $results = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
$data['rows'][] = array(
'id' => $row['id'],
'cell' => array($row['id'], $row['authorisation'], $row['boxref'], $row['custref'], date('d/m/y H:i:s',strtotime($row['intake_date'])), date('d/m/Y',$row['fileout_date']), date('d/m/Y',$row['filein_date']), date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['destroy_date'])),$row['filestatus']));
}
echo $json->encode($data); thanks

Answer (score 1):

> this portion of code is outputing 01/01/1970. is my code incorrect?

That depends on what is in $row['destroy_date']. If that's actually a date, you have to convert it to a timestamp first (strtotime). If it's null or 0, it converts to Epoch (1-1-1970).

I've found [DateTime](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) a lot easier to use;

```
$datetime = new DateTime( $row['destroy_date'] );
echo $datetime->format( 'd-m-Y' );
```

Comment: so have i got to use this on every date row in my page? thanks

Answer (score 0):

probably value into `$row['destroy_date']` are null or incorrect for data formatting, check value with `echo $row['destroy_date'];`

Comment: here is what echoes: 2028-09-12